# Limit of the expectation of the sum

Tags: probability, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

Show that for $g(t)= E \left\{\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{(iut)^{n}}{n!}\right\}$ that $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|g(t)|}{t} =0$.

I think I should bound it and then use LDCT, but I'm having trouble doing that.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $i$ the imaginary unity? Is $u$ a random variable? If it is how is it distributed, or is it a general continuous random variable? Is it non-negative? What is LDCT?

Comment: i is the imaginary unity. u is a general continuous random variable, and LDCT is Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem.